# Get the number of non existing files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have wrote this bash script to automate the process of finding the files that are missing:

```
echo "--|";
echo "  |";
read -p "  ->Enter the text file that contains the video files to look for: " fname
if [ ! -e "$fname" ]; then
        echo "  |";
        echo "--> The file $fname is not valid or doesn't exist";
else
        echo "  |";
        read -p "  ->File ready to be processed, enter the path where to look for the files: [/home/efeikuna/public_html/files/flv/]": path
        if [ ! -e "$path" ]; then
                path="/home/efeikuna/public_html/files/flv/";
        fi
                i=0
                for line in `cat $fname`;
                do
                        file=$path$line;
                        #echo "   |";
                        if [ ! -e $file ]; then
                                echo "   -> $i - $file => DOES NOT EXIST";
                        fi
                        i=$(expr $i + 1);
                        #if [ $i == 3 ]; then
                        #       break;
                        #fi
                done
fi
```

The script is working, but it needs some more features, so I was hopping you can guide/point me to the right way:

- I need to get the total number of non existing files and the number of the existing ones
- What do you recommend to use to check the integrity of the file (usually flv files and txt files, but will be other in the future)
- If the `if [ ! -e $file ]` enters, how can I match `$fname` with an `locate $fname` just to see if the file exists some where else? If `locate $fname` returns true, than show where is located, if not, continue.
- What do you recommend to use to write a file where it indicates the existing and missing files by separate, ex:

  ```
  Found Files:
  ____________
     ---- asdasd.flv
     ---- asdasd1.flv
     ---- asdasd2.flv
     ---- asdasd3.flv
     ---- asdasd4.flv

  Missing Files:
  ____________
     ---- bsdasd.flv
     ---- bsdasd1.flv
     ---- bsdasd2.flv
     ---- bsdasd3.flv
     ---- bsdasd4.flv
  ```
- Any possible improvements?

Thanks and sorry for any possible misunderstandings

Answer (score 1):

`md5sum` (and `sha1sum`) produces a file that contains checksums. Simply parse the result of running `md5sum -c` against the file containing the checksums to see how many files are valid, invalid, or missing.

Comment: Ignacio, I don't have experience with checksums at all (going to read right now some documentation) but will it work if I don't have any checksum for any file? I mean, I don't think that there is anything like checksum for any file or group of files.

Comment: You have to assume that the files have good integrity now, and calculate their checksums. Then in the future you can validate those checksum to detects whether bits in the files have changed.

Answer (score 1):

**.I need to get the total number of non existing files and the number of the existing ones**
With this, I use python instead of bash, actually it can be done with bash, but it found python is more efficient for this purpose:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import os
 import sys

 def check_file(directory, filelist):
     is_file = []
     not_file = []
     with open(filelist) as f:
         for filename in f:
             fp = directory + '/' + filename.strip()
             print fp
             if os.path.isfile(fp): is_file.append(filename.strip())
             else: not_file.append(filename.strip())
     print "Number of file: %s" %(len(is_file))
     for item in is_file: print "----- %s" %(item)
     print "Number of non file: %s" %(len(not_file))
     for item in not_file: print "----- %s" %(item)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     if len(sys.argv) < 3:
         print "Usage: %s [dir] [listfile]" %(sys.argv[0])
         sys.exit(2)
     directory = sys.argv[1]
     filelist  = sys.argv[2]
     check_file(directory, filelist)
```

**What do you recommend to use to check the integrity of the file (usually flv files and txt files, but will be other in the future)**

md5sum is the right way, but it can be **very slow** if you have more and large files. Use **inotify** instead. With inotify, you will be notified when a file was updated.

**If the if [ ! -e $file ] enters, how can I match $fname with an locate $fname just to see if the file exists some where else? If locate $fname returns true, than show where is located, if not, continue.**

Here is another python way:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for f in [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename)) for filename in files]:
         fn = filename.split['/'][-1]
         if fn == file_you_want_to_search_for:
             print filename
```

Hope this help.